# Show all items for user with admin role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a help desk application using C# MVC. I have a 'Ticket' view. In my Ticket model I have a 'RaisedBy' property. I have been able to apply some logic to show a logged in user their tickets. The next step I'd like to show all Tickets to a user with the role 'admin'

I've created a foreach loop to return all items and pop them into a table. Here's what I've tried so inside my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.RaisedBy == User.Identity.Name) { 
    if(item.RaisedBy == User.IsInRole ="Admin")
```

This gives me the error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method-group'
```

I've also tried:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
{
    if (item.RaisedBy = User.IsInRole("Admin")  {
```

Which gives:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'
```

I'm not very experienced with C# so any pointers or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry you can't assign `=` in an if condition. You should use `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.IsInRole` acts on the current logged in user and it is a method.  It returns a `bool`.

You're using the wrong syntax here: `if (item.RaisedBy = User.IsInRole("Admin"))`. It should be `if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))`.

Once you've confirmed the `item.RaisedBy` matches the current user then you just need to check if the current user has admin role.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    // if item.RaisedBy is current user
    if (item.RaisedBy == User.Identity.Name)
    { 
        // if current user is in "admin" role
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> You're not using equality comparison `==`. By using `=` you're assigning the righter variable to the left.

Your loop should be:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.RaisedBy == User.Identity.Name) { 
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        // Other code..
```